# Python Mutation testing reporting in Azure devOps Build Pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, mutation

I created a Mutation testing for Python programming in Azure DevOps Pipeline using Mutpy. But I am not able to report it. Is there any known extension for Azure DevOps for Mutpy - mutation testing?

it would be great if you can help out. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Extension [Mutation Report Publisher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stryker-mutator.mutation-report-publisher) may help you. With this extension you add the mutation report to your build summary so you can view the mutation test result on azure devops.

> To use this extension all you have to do is add the `Publish Mutation Report` task to your build pipeline and set the path where the html
> report was generated.
>
> Note: Make sure you add the publish step after the mutation test step
> and that you configure the mutation testing tool to generate the html
> report.